# Is there a limit of maximum compaction for materials?

Tags: condensed-matter, density

The question is say there is a block of steel $1\,\mathrm{m} \times 1\,\, \mathrm{m} \times 1\,\mathrm{m}$ $\left(L \times W \times H\right)$ is there a limit the material can be compressed in an isostatic manner?

For example, the mass of said block above would weigh $8.050 \, \mathrm{kg} ,$ is it possible to reduce volume say by half so to $0.5 \, {\mathrm{m}}^{3}$ yet still weigh $8.050 \, \mathrm{kg} ,$ furthermore can compaction still be achieved from this point onward if force is infinite.

Also how would one calculate the required force to for continuation of volume reduction?

Answer (score 6):

In a way, no, there isn't, although what you would end up with is not steel in any reasonable sense.

If you are willing to go far enough you could use this block of steel as part of a [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star).  The density of a neutron star, from the previous reference is between $3.7 \times 10^{17}\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$ and $5.9 \times 10^{17}\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$.  So your block of steel would have a volume of about $1.5\times 10^{-14}\,\mathrm{m^3}$.

The resulting thing is not really steel of course, it's just neutrons as the electrons and protons have been crushed together into neutrons.

That is probably as far as you can go while still maintaining any pretence, however weak, that the thing you end up with is somehow the same block of steel (there are hypothesized [quark stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_star) which would be even denser but are not known to exist).

But, as certified mad scientists, we can go further: if you spend enough time piling matter onto a neutron star (for instance by arranging life so that another neutron star collides with it), or if, when trying to make a neutron star you start with a star which is too big, then the resulting collapse doesn't stop when it gets to be a neutron star: indeed it doesn't stop at all, and what you end up with is a [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).

It's not obvious how to characterise the density of a black hole (and there are also issues around the collapse process itself which I am skirting around by talking about black holes which already exist): you could talk about the mass contained within its event horizon but that's not really right; or you could talk about the density of the singularity, which is not really a well-posed question at all (both because the singularity is not really a thing and because I think everyone assumes that singularities don't actually happen).  But I think it's safe to say that the densities involved are extremely high: far higher than the densities in a neutron star and (in the simple-minded GR view) essentially infinite.

There is no sense at all that a black hole as traditionally understood somehow 'remembers' that it was once made of steel, or anything else, according to the famous [no-hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem).  Indeed this is one of the problems with black holes, because they conflict with other parts of physics which would very much like that memory to exist: I don't know how resolved this problem is (except that I'm pretty sure the other parts of physics must be right!).

---

Just to be clear: I've talked about 'making' a neutron star above as if it's something you could do.  It's not, but it *is* something the universe does, and the things that end up as neutron stars and black holes do I think contain a lot of iron as that's the end point of fusion processes in stars.  So there's a sense that there are, out there, things that were once made of iron which have now been crushed down into neutron stars and black holes.

Answer (score 1):

For *linear* material behaviour, you can do the calculation using the stress-strain relationships found in any material science textbook.

Youngs modulus for steel is about 200,000 MPa.

1 MPa (megapascal) is about 100 tonnes force / square meter.

To reduce the volume by about **1%** (not half!) would need a presure of about 2,000 MPa or a force of about 200,000 tonnes.

To reduce the volume by **50%** would need much more than 50 times that force, because of the nonlinear behaviour of the material - but applying a force of the order of 10 million or maybe 100 million tons isn't interesting enough for me (as an engineer not a physicist!) to be worth thinking about how to get a better estimate.

Comment: You want bulk modulus, not Young’s. But they’re not much different.